# How to increase privacy on Facebook from non-friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I happened to see my Facebook account from a profile who isn't my friend. Basically everything is public. I thought I had fixed this with the settings.

[image: screen shot of facebook settings]

My issues are:

1. I don't want strangers to see articles I click "Post to Facebook" and I don't want strangers to see my status updates (so basically I don't want strangers to see my timeline).
2. I don't want strangers to see my photos/videos.
3. I don't want strangers to see my "Places" and "Music" and "Likes".
4. I don't want strangers to see the schools I attended.

Answer (score 1):

(1). When you post or share a post on Facebook, make them "friends only" by clicking on the down arrow left to the *Post* button

[image: post on fb]

(2). Use the above *friends only* option when you upload a photo, a photo album or a video
You can change that privacy after you upload photos/videos too.
Cover pictures are always public. You can not change it.
Profile pictures allow to edit privacy for pictures one by one.
Other picture albums allow to apply privacy for all the photos in album at once.

(4). Go to *About* tab of your profile
Click on *Edit* button of the *Work and Education* section
Change the privacy by clicking on the down arrows in front of each school you attend

Note: I have no idea about your issue number 3

The photos uploaded from smartphone should be in a album called *Mobile Uploads*.
Privacy of each photo of that album can be edited one by one like in *Profile Pictures* album.
[image: Mobile Uploads]

The above tool-tip appears when you put cursor on the gear icon of the *Mobile Uploads* album.

Comment: There were some photos I uploaded straight from my smartphone and these still appear public to everyone and I can't figure out how to change that?

Comment: Edited the post by adding answer to the above comment at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Ok I found the "Mobile Uploads" album, now what? In the corner there is a gear icon when hovered over says "you can change the audience for each photo in this album" and nothing happens when you click on it. When I go into the album and click on pictures I see no options for privacy.

Comment: When you click on a picture and open it using photo viewer, there should be a down arrow next to the "Date Posted". Click on it and edit privacy.

Comment: that's what I've been waiting for someone to say