# How to prevent people from finding me by name search on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-privacy

I don't want my profile to appear in search results for user profiles.

Is it possible to configure my account to be unsearchable?

Comment: You may find this useful: [How to increase privacy on Facebook from non-friends?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/59460/354)

Answer (score 3):

On the [Privacy](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy) tab in your settings, you'll find a number of settings, however there's no way to become completely incognito. If that's what you want, you'll need to leave Facebook.

Some things you might do to increase your privacy:

- Set "Who can send you friend requests?" to "Friends of Friends"
- Set "Who can look you up using the email address you provided?" to "Friends"
- Set "Who can look you up using the phone number you provided?" to "Friends"
- Under "Do you want other search engines to link to your timeline?" uncheck "Let other search engines link to your timeline"

But if someone knows your name, they can search for it in Facebook. All you can do is hide everything to non-Friends. You can't hide your name, your profile photo, or your cover photo, however.

You might try a pseudonym, but you may run afoul of Facebook's "real names" policy.