# How to prevent users from finding you by your email address in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I want to have enough closed account in Facebook. I do not want that people knowing my email address can find me.
I know the following cases but they do not target the problem, since I have all those configurations mentioned there in the strictest levels. 
Users knowing my email address can still find my profile in Facebook

- [How to prevent people from finding me by name search on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84558/how-to-prevent-people-from-finding-me-by-name-search-on-facebook)
- [How to increase privacy on Facebook from non-friends?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59460/how-to-increase-privacy-on-facebook-from-non-friends)

It can also be that the users have found me by phone number.

My settings

- Who can look you up using the email address you provided? Friends (strictest).
- Who can look you up using the phone number you provided? Friends (strictest).

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you're trying to improve your privacy on Facebook, the answers to [How to prevent people from finding me by name search on Facebook?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84558/354) and [How to increase privacy on Facebook from non-friends?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/59460/354) may be useful.

Comment: @ale Thank you for the comment! It is clearer now. I went through those two links but nothing relevant there. I have strictest settings there already. Users knowing my email address can still find my facebook profile.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the strictest privacy settings, then your options are to quit Facebook, or create a new email address that you use only for Facebook, and don't tell anyone else that new address.

Even so, you'll probably still get some unsolicited Friend requests, especially if you have a common name. (Not posting anything on Facebook probably won't protect you.)

Comment: It is unbelievable that Facebook is leaking my privacy information without my permission.

Comment: It's a social network. Its raison d'etre is to help people connect. Making it easy to find people is what they're all about. There are plenty of people who won't use Fbook for this very reason.

Comment: I really do not need help to connect myself to others. I do know how to do it. The case is about the automatism which Facebook uses without user permission.